# User can't access to group permission directory

Tags: linux, permissions, user-groups

I have a user `jenkins` in group `jenkins`. I want to have access to the directory `/var/www/html/`, so I have changed the directory group from `root` to `jenkins`.

```
$ ll /var/www
...
drwxrwx---. 7 root jenkins ... html
...
$ groups
jenkins
$ cd /var/www/html
-bash: cd/var/www/html: Permission denied
```

User from `/etc/passwd`:
    jenkins:x:779:779::/home/usr:/bin/bash

The owner and group of `/var` and `/var/www` are `root`. As I understand I shouldn't change their group as well, only the directory I want to access.

Do you have any idea why this isn't working?

EDIT:
    $ ls -l /var
    total 97
    ...
    drwxrwx---. 8 root root ... www
    ...

Sorry for not displaying the full output, it is from an offline computer. I don't know what is executable path but this file is the only one that looks different:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root ... mail -> spool/mail
```

Comment: Could you also add the output from `ls -l /var` ?  (Trying to see if there is a eXecutable path from /var to /var/www/ to /var/www/html to cd into).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with perms from parents folders, if you want to read and change into a directory you have to get read and execute perms on the folders and its parents folders.
Check that ownership and bits mode of the following folders:

- / = mode: 755, user: root, group: root
- /var = mode: 755, user: root, group: root
- /var/www = mode: 750, user: WebSrvUsr**, group: WebSrvGrp**
- /var/www/html = mode: 750, user: WebSrvUsr**, group: jenkins

** WebSrvUsr and WebSrvGrp depends of distro

And finally, your user have to be member of the following groups: WebSrvGrp, jenkins.

If this does not work, you could check selinux or apparmor (getenforce)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure either:

- a) `/var/` has 755 permission (recommended), or
- b) `/var`'s ownership is set to `root:jenkins` (not recommended).

Comment: It is set to 755.

Comment: How about `/var/www/html`? It should be the same permission. Permission change usually need to be applied recursively using the `-R` switch.

Comment: `/var/www/html/` is set to 770 recursively, why should I change it to 755? I don't want other people outside the group and the owner to have access.

Comment: It is very weird... I have tried to change the owner of `/var/www/html` from `root` to `jenkins`, and I still don't have access. Is this directory protected or something?

Comment: `/var/www` sould be 755 as well